# Uncaught TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS and trying to create a simple todo list app from a tutorial.
This is the code in App.js:

```
 addItem = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newItem = this.state.currentItem;
    if (newItem.text !== "") {
      const items = [...this.state.items, newItem];
      this.setState({
        items: items,
        currentItem: { text: "", key: "" }
      });
    }
  };
```

It throws:

Uncaught TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function
    at App._this.addItem (App.js:89)

If I try to change it to e.preventDefault and bind it in constructor, the error goes away but the form still reloads on submit (i.e preventDefault does not work). Can someone please help me with this?

Editing to add how addItem is called:

This is my TodoList.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class TodoList extends Component{
    componentDidUpdate(){
        if(this.props.inputElement.current){
       this.props.inputElement.current.focus();
        }
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="todoListMain">
                <div className="header">
                    <form onSubmit={this.props.addItem}>
                        <input 
                            placeholder="Task" 
                            ref={this.props.addItem}
                            value={this.props.currentItem.text}
                            onChange={this.props.handleInput}
                        />
                        <button type="submit">Add Task</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default TodoList;
```

Comment: How is the function addItem called?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us how the handler is installed on the form

Comment: Edited the post. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the ref attribute in the input tag, it'll works fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-womnwm

ref in the input field passes an object with some data about the tag with properties like tagName, attributes, innerHTML etc., and it wouldn't have a preventDefault method

Comment: The link [https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-womnwm] is broken.